# register a button click in an if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, button

Here is my code:

```
else if (roomNumber == 3) {
            txtAreaDisplay.append("Oh no, it looks like you have run into a monster!\n"
                    + "The monster runs straight at you, looking for a fight.\n"
                    + "Are you going to fight, or run?\n");

            //fight
            if (btnFight.getModel().isPressed()) {
                txtAreaDisplay.append("You have chosen to fight the monster!\n");
            }

            //run
            else if (btnRun.getModel().isPressed()) {
                txtAreaDisplay.append("You have chosen to attempt to run away from the monster!\n");
            }
        }
```

My question is, how do I go about registering the button click in the if statement (if that makes sense)? I have the line: `(btnFight.getModel().isPressed())` but that does not seem to work because when I press the button, the next line is not outputted.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should be using either a `JToggledButton`, `JCheckBox` or `JRadioButton`, depending on what you want to do, then you can us `isSelected` to determine which buttons have been selected.  You can use a `ButtonGroup` to restrict the selection to a single button as well. See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) (assuming Swing)

Comment: I am only using a JButton.. So, if I switch it to a JToggledButton will I be able to use my .isPressed statement?

Comment: I just switched it for a JToggledButton instead of a JButton. Using my previous statement, and switching it to .isSelected did not work. Sorry if I am missing something. This is fairly new to me.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: My GUI has a button (named btnFight) and another button (named btnRun). I am using an if statement in my code to see if the user has pressed either the Fight button, or the Run button. If the fight button is pressed, I want to output "You have chosen to fight the monster". I'm just looking for the correct code to register if the button has been clicked.

Comment: I am not sure how to attach a runnable example, so I tried to explain my situation a little better.

Comment: You should use this condition inside a button even listener which is registered with that buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you have here is more fundimental. The button press is an event, as such it is asychronous to your prompt.  By the time the player has read your prompting message and started to respond the if then else has already been processed and neither event has happened...so you get no message.

the place you want to put the txtAreaDisplay appends is in the button press event code.  That way the prompt happens and the player makes their choice. the action happens when the player moves...  Now the user should only have a short time to respond before the monster makes the choice for them.

Comment: Thank you for that reply. I definitely over looked that. I put the appends in the button event handler, and it does exactly as I hoped. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way.

**Example with Anonymous ActionListener.**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ButtonE extends JFrame {

    JButton btnFight = new JButton("Figth");
    JButton btnRun = new JButton("Run");
    JTextArea txtAreaDisplay = new JTextArea();
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    public ButtonE() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setVisible(true);
        pnl.add(btnFight);
        pnl.add(btnRun);
        Container cntnr = this.getContentPane();
        cntnr.add(txtAreaDisplay, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cntnr.add(pnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        btnFight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                txtAreaDisplay.append("Oh no, it looks like you have run into a monster!\n"
                        + "The monster runs straight at you, looking for a fight.\n"
                        + "Are you going to fight, or run?\n");
                txtAreaDisplay.append("You have chosen to fight the monster!\n");
            }

        });
        btnRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                txtAreaDisplay.append("Oh no, it looks like you have run into a monster!\n"
                        + "The monster runs straight at you, looking for a fight.\n"
                        + "Are you going to fight, or run?\n");
                txtAreaDisplay.append("You have chosen to attempt to run away from the monster!\n");
            }

        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ButtonE();
    }
}
```

**Or You can do it the Following way by using an Interface.**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class ButtonE extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    JButton btnFight = new JButton("Figth");
    JButton btnRun = new JButton("Run");
    JTextArea txtAreaDisplay = new JTextArea();
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    public ButtonE() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setVisible(true);
        pnl.add(btnFight);
        pnl.add(btnRun);
        Container cntnr = this.getContentPane();
        cntnr.add(txtAreaDisplay, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cntnr.add(pnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        btnFight.addActionListener(this);
        btnRun.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ButtonE();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        txtAreaDisplay.append("Oh no, it looks like you have run into a monster!\n"
                + "The monster runs straight at you, looking for a fight.\n"
                + "Are you going to fight, or run?\n");

        //fight
        if (ae.getSource() == btnFight) {
            txtAreaDisplay.append("You have chosen to fight the monster!\n");
        } //run
        else if (ae.getSource() == btnRun) {
            txtAreaDisplay.append("You have chosen to attempt to run away from the monster!\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JToggleButton and then use an ActionListener to help perform the action you want to run. This should help and will perform whatever has been clicked it is being used as a different version of an if-statement.

```
  tglFight.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tglFight.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        txtAreaDisplay.append("You have chosen to fight the monster!\n");
    }
});

 tglRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tglRun.setBackground(Color.RED);
        txtAreaDisplay.append("You have chosen to attempt to run away from the monster!\n");;
    }
});
```